# Select all text of Outlook message using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to code a shortcut that will quickly convert a text typed in a wrong language to the correct letters(assuming there are only two languages: English and Hebrew). This happens when one doesn't switch to the correct language and starts to type without looking at the screen.

In order to implement this I need to:

-> get the just typed text in a message/search/any other current field

-> select all

-> do the manipulation I need

-> paste the result of manipulatedText(initialText) to the place it came from.

I am not familiar with outlook object model so can someone please suggest a general guideline for implementation especially the objects I will have to approach.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest versions of Outlook use Word as an email editor. You are free to use the Word object model for manipulating the body in the way you need. The *WordEditor* property of the *Inspector* class returns an instance of the *Document* class from the Word object model.

All possible ways of working with bodies are described in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012.aspx) in MSDN.

But the Word object model (nor Outlook) doesn't provide any events for letting others know that a phrase or word was entered/typed. However, you may try to use a timer to check the state of the editor and do whatever you need if required.